# Rotate CAShapeLayer

Tags: objective-c, cashapelayer

I'm trying to rotate a CAShapeLayer in place

```
             UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
             CGFloat originx = (97.5+250);
             CGFloat originy = (205+250);
             [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(originx,originy)];
             [aPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(originx+15, originy-30) radius:15 startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360) clockwise:YES];
             [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(originx+30,originy)];
             CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
             shapeLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(originx, originy);
             shapeLayer.path = [aPath CGPath];
             shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
             shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
             shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
             [aPath closePath];
             shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(310 * M_PI/180, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
             [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

I want to rotate the shape around an axis within the shape itself (the code above makes my little shape rotate around an axis several hundred pixels from the actual centre.

I felt this should be controlled with an anchorpoint like this one:

```
shapeLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(originx, originy);
```

but it seems to do nothing within the code.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`anchorPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410817-anchorpoint?language=objc) is relative to the bounds of the layer. You can't use the anchor point to place your layer. Instead you can place your shape relative to the zero point, rotate it, and the move it to the desired point. Rotation and translation are done by the transform.

Comment: So I: 1)Place 2)Transform then 3)Move?

Comment: Yes, where the two last operations are a concatenation of two transforms. (Tip: For testing and debugging it is easier to start with a smaller degree (say 5°). So you can see if the layer is moving towards a wrong direction.)

Comment: Hmm the only way I can do this is moving it first. I felt that CATransform3D translate = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(52.7, 45.46, 0);
should do the job but it doesn't

Comment: Take a look at `CATransform3DTranslate` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/1436574-catransform3dtranslate?language=objc).